# Is Hilbert's space-filling curve measure preserving?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, measure-theory, proof-verification

Say $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]^d$ is the $n$-th iteration of a $d$-dimensional Hilbert curve touring its range. Is it true that for any open $S\subset [0,1]^d$, then amount of time $f_n$ spends in $S$ is approximately  $\mathrm{vol}(S)$?

That is, for $S\subset [0,1]^d$ open, taking $f^{-1}_n(S)=\{t:f_n(t)\in S\}\subset [0,1],$ is it true that:

\begin{equation}
    \mu(f^{-1}_n(S))\to_n \mu(S)?
\end{equation}

---

I think so.

> Each $f_n$ maps to the boundary of some lattice of cuboids, $(c^{(n)}_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda^{(n)}}$, where each $c^{(n)}_\lambda$ corresponds to a single cuboidal cell in $[0,1]^d$ with side length $\ell^{(n)}$.
>   Take $\mathcal{S}^{(n)}$ to be the collection of cuboids $c^{(n)}_\lambda$ which come within $\ell^{(n)}$ of $S$ and compute:
>   \begin{align} \mu(S) &\leq \mu(\cup_{\mathcal{S}^{(n)}})\\
> &=\left|\mathcal{S}^{(n)}\right|\cdot(\ell^{(n)})^d \\
> &\leq \mu(f_n^{-1}(\cup_{\mathcal{S}^{(n)}}))/(\ell^{(n)})^d\cdot (\ell^{(n)})^d \\
> &\leq \mu(f^{-1}_n(\cup_{\mathcal{S}^{(n)}}\backslash S))+\mu(f^{-1}_n(S)) \\ 
> &\leq O(1/n)+\mu(f_n^{-1}(S)).
> \end{align} 
>   Get a similar upper bound on $
> \mu(f_n^{-1}(S))$ by identically inspecting the collection of cuboids contained in $S$ and at least $\ell^{(n)}$ away from the boundary of $S$.

Is this correct? Is there a better way?

Comment: The limit Hilbert curve $f$, by construction, has the "bi-measure-preserving" property: *if $I\subset[0,1]$ is Borel then $\mu(I)=\mu(f(I))$.* I want measure preservation in the other direction which is maybe what is implied by the *bi-*, but I wanted proof. Maybe what I am asking for is obvious.